# Series with ArcTan gives wrong symbolic answer in Wolfram Language

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, symbolic, series-expansion, trigonometry

**Bug introduced after 9 and persisting through 13.1. Resolved in 13.2**

---

Recently, I have found a very bad problem with Wolfram Language. It gives the wrong answer for a quite simple expression!

When calculating

```
Series[ArcTan[A + 1/x], {x, 0, 2},  Assumptions -> A > 0 && x > 0]
```

I get the wrong answer (tested in wolfram cloud and in Mathematica 12.1.1.0)

[image: wrong answer]

I am absolutely sure that the correct answer should be

[image: correct answer]

There is a plot of these functions to demonstrate the issue

[image: plot demonstration]

How to get rid of the problem?

**UPD** More obvious issue (thank to @MichaelE2):
[image]

**UPD#2** Working around.

The result in v10.3 is correct.

The result in v11.3 is incorrect.

The [corresponding post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2209736?p_p_auth=gRK8fDP9) is in Wolfram Community.

Comment: Not a particularly satisfying workaround: For `n=2`, `Series[Series[ArcTan[A + 1/x], {x, 0, 2 n}, Assumptions -> A > 0 && x > 0], {x, 0, n}]`.  Seems to work and be necessary for higher `n`. -- I'd say it's a bug and you should report it to WRI.

Comment: You might think this is a better workaround: `Series[ArcTan[A + x], {x, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> A > 0 && x > 0] /. Infinity -> 0`.  Or this: `ReplacePart[Series[ArcTan[A + x], {x, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> A > 0 && x > 0], 2 -> 0]`

Comment: When you calculate the series, you assume `A` constant and `x` variable. However, in your plot, `x` is constant and `A` variable. You can not this purely graphically, the slope for A==0 should be negative not positive. When you plot `x` as a variable, the plot looks much better.

Comment: This does look to be a bug. Compare to `In[291]:= Series[ArcTan[aa + x], {x, Infinity, 2}, 
 Assumptions -> aa > 0 && x > 1000]

Out[291]= SeriesData[x, 
DirectedInfinity[1], {Rational[1, 2] Pi, -1, aa}, 0, 3, 1]`

Comment: @DanielHuber Indeed, for A==0 the problem is gone and for greater A the result deviates. So, I think the plot on A should indicate the problem for A!=0.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for the comment! Indeed, if increase the depth of a series, several first terms are correct, while several last are incorrect. Updated the question.

Comment: @DanielHuber When you plot vs. `x`, you should try to show the series is `O[x]^3`. It's clearly not, but the  OP's "correct answer" is: `Block[{
  A = 2,
  f = (ArcTan[
       A + 1/x] - {Normal@
        Series[ArcTan[A + 1/x], {x, 0, 2}, 
         Assumptions -> A > 0 && x > 0],
       \[Pi]/2 - x + A x^2})/x^3},
 Plot[f, {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 16]
 ]`

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: Result in _v9.0.1_ is correct: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V118C.png

Comment: I'll add the note that `Assuming[A > 0 && x > 0, Asymptotic[ArcTan[A + 1/x], {x, 0, 2}]]` gives the correct result.

Answer (score 4):

The issue appears to have been resolved in `13.2.0`

[image]